# I am making an app using react & node, how should I design my database (Schema)

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, mongodb, data-modeling

How should I approach to schema design for my app? What are the important points to  remember when doing schema design and how should be different models in my node app relate to each other. Any explanation for simple CRUD app?

Answer (score 0):

When you start designing your data model there are two things that I find very important. `Cardinality` and `Association`.

Cardinality just means how many of one thing is associated to another thing. For example, in a library application, a `Book` includes zero or many `Chapters`.

Associated is just what's related to what. Again, `Chapter`s are associated to a `Book`. `Page`s are associated to `Chapter`s. A `Book` definitely has at least one `Author`.

When you start designing the schema, you need to realize the relationship which is either `1-1`, `1-many` or `many-many`. For example:

- A `Book` might have multiple `Author`s and each `Author` might have written many `Book`s. So this is a `many-many` relationship.
- A `Book` might have many `Chapter`s but the same exact `Chapter` only appears in that `Book`. So this is a `1-many` relationship.

Once you have these figured out you can create tables. For `1-m` you just use a Foreign Key of the `1` side in the `m` side table. For the `m-m`, you usually create an intermediate table that holds the Primary key of each side.

If you had given more info on *what* you are trying to make, I could use a more familiar example. Good luck.